# Access OpenGL Textures used by Unity from C++ in Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, opengl-es, android-ndk, texture2d

I created a scene in Unity and placed two planes into it. I would now like to access the Texture of these planes to use them with OpenGL. AFAIK Unity is using OpenGL, so the Texture should be available somehow.
I need this to decode an MJPEG stream in C++ and display it on the texture. Has anyone tried to access Unity textures from native C++ code?

Comment: We do this the other way around quite a bit (Textures from native to Unity), mainly for camera capture.  BUT I would think you would want to get a handle to the texture in C# and then pass it `extern` to c++.  As long as the GC doesn't move the address then you should be good.

Comment: Textures from Native to Unity would be even better! Somehow I did not think of that. How do you do this? How can I place a texture in my scene that is written from native?

Comment: Can't spend the time writing a comprehensive answer.  But basically generate the GLTexture in native.  Have a C callback that passes this via `MonoPInvoke` to Unity, send the `IntPtr` result to some class that will unpack it via it's `GLTextureID` then you can use a RawImage to draw on.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this.

Comment: Well, I found a different solution to my problem. I am using this for camera capture as well. I am getting a MJPEG stream from a USB camera via V4L2. V4L2 gives me an RGB buffer that I pass to C# in a callback. I then convert the buffer to a C# byte[] with Marshal.Copy() and load it into the texture with the LoadImage function of Texture2D.
I am gonna need to read the OpenGL texture from C++ later, so I am going to update again once I did that, to give a complete answer to my question.

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: Sorry @ThunderWiring, I found a workaround back then and did not need to access the textures.

Comment: @BenT can you share the code?

Comment: I left the organization I was doing this for a few years ago, so unfortunately I do not have access to the code anymore.